# GADTs for multiple generics transformations in Rust

Tags: generics, rust, gadt

I'm trying to design an execution graph with Recursive Generics Enums in Rust. I want to make an `eval` function which computes a predefined `map` closure recursively, but each `map` function could change the enum type so I get a compilation error due the different types. Here is my code:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

enum ExecutionGraph<T, H, F = fn(T) -> H> {
    Cons(Vec<T>),
    Map(F, Rc<ExecutionGraph<T, H>>),
}

// Impl for add a Cons "node" or a Map "node"
impl<T, H> ExecutionGraph<T, H, fn(T) -> H> {
    fn new_data(data: Vec<T>) -> Self {
        ExecutionGraph::Cons(data)
    }

    fn add_map(a_function: fn(T) -> H, execution_graph: ExecutionGraph<T, H, fn(T) -> H>) -> Self {
        ExecutionGraph::Map(a_function, Rc::new(execution_graph))
    }
}

// Complete evaluation of the execution graph
fn eval<T, H>(execution_graph: &ExecutionGraph<T, H, fn(T) -> H>) -> Vec<T>
where
    T: std::clone::Clone,
    std::vec::Vec<T>: std::iter::FromIterator<H>,
{
    match execution_graph {
        ExecutionGraph::Cons(data) => data.to_vec(),
        ExecutionGraph::Map(closure, e1) => eval(&(*e1)).into_iter().map(closure).collect(),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let execution_graph = ExecutionGraph::new_data(vec![1, 2, 3]);

    // let map_function: fn(u32) -> u32 = |x: u32| x * 8; // This work!
    let map_function: fn(u32) -> bool = |x: u32| x % 2 == 0; // This doesn't
    let execution_graph_2 = ExecutionGraph::add_map(map_function, execution_graph);
    let execution_result = eval(&execution_graph_2);

    println!("Result of execution = {:#?}", execution_result);
}
```

The `add_data` and `add_map` functions work as expected. But then when I call the `eval` function I'm getting the following error:

```
   |     let execution_result = eval(&execution_graph_2);
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected u32, found bool
   |
   = note: expected type `&ExecutionGraph<_, _>`
              found type `&ExecutionGraph<u32, bool>`>`
```

**Why am I getting this error?** I defined to get a generic argument and a generic function which could change the result type. **How could allow all possible transformations in the data? In the future, there will be a lot of more functions with the same problem, such as a cartesian product which returns a tuple**. Note that if the closure has the same return type as the input there is no problem. If someone could give me a hand with this problem I would appreciate it.

Comment: You wrote `Vec<T>: std::iter::FromIterator<H>`, but `Vec<u32>` does not implement `FromIterator<bool>`.

Comment: How could solve the problem? If I remove that It throws `a collection of type 'std::vec::Vec<T>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=H>'` in the `collect()` part. I need to return a generic type as the `map` function comes from the user and It could change the Vec type

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you're trying to do. If you want to turn an `H` into a `T`, you need `fn(H) -> T`, not `fn(T) -> H` -- is that the problem?

Comment: Nono, I receive a `fn(T) -> H`. Because the `Map` enum could have a function which changes the type of the recursive `Cons`. The problem is that `eval` expects to return a `T` and not and `H`. That's why it throws that I can't have a `fn(32) -> bool` function. I would like to know if is possible to have generics `Map` functions like the one in the question, which transforms u32 to bool elements.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't understand. A function can't change the type of a value; that's not how types work. I could guess you want some kind of *wrapper* that encapsulates the function and an inner type, but then first you'd need the wrapper to convert both ways -- not just `T` to `H` but `H` to `T` depending on how it's being used -- and secondly you'd need the "inner" `ExecutionGraph` to be a different type, not just the same as the "outer" type. Also, it kind of seems like you're trying to do things both at compile time and at run time in a way that doesn't jive, but that's a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by a user in [my question in the official forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/recursive-enums-with-changing-types-in-rust/35836) of Rust. This language has no support for Generalized Algebraic Data Types (GADTs) which would be the right tool to solve this kind of problems.

As an alternative, instead of proposing a scheme where the types belong to the ENUM making it not very flexible, a class approach is proposed, which is allowed to introduce new types.

I do not put the code here so that it can be consulted directly in the question with the edits or new answers that may arise.